# Finding the right amazon ec2 ubuntu instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have to set up an aws ec2 ubuntu 10.04 instance, I tried few instance but when  I read the description of the image I realized that they are meant for testing so I am looking for the right image so that I use it for my web app. If you have experience feel good factor about the image which u have used it. Kindly let me know, that would be of great help.Presently I was using this image ami-6a3dcf03

Comment: There is a more complete answer to this question on [ask ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/53582/how-do-i-know-what-ubuntu-ami-to-launch-on-ec2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the full Ubuntu amazon image lists for production use online, for example [10.04](http://uec-images.ubuntu.com/releases/10.04/release/) and [10.10](http://uec-images.ubuntu.com/releases/maverick/release/).

Comment: The official instance doesnt have small instance type so install java I need to switch to large and then install it and again switch back to micro? Will it be expensive if I turn to large just to install java Mr David?

Comment: I have an image snapshot for 64-bit Ubuntu with Sun JDK 6 for this reason. I have made the snapshot public, its ID is ami-30be4359. I have done these things only to the Ubuntu image: 1) Uncommented the multiverse and partner lines in /etc/apt/sources.list, 2) sudo apt-get update, 3) sudo apt-get install sun-jdk6 and 4) sudo apt-get install ec2-api-tools. When the image becomes public you will be able to run that straight on a micro instance in US-East.

Comment: so can i start using that instance now, or i need for some more time david. and I was not knowing that I need to take the snap shot the instance and they I have to configure according to my requirement,, I was working directly on the the ubuntu official instance.

Comment: @Jeevan Dongre Ah yes, forgot to change permission, done now.

Comment: I tried to find ami-30be4359 on AWS but it came up with no search results.  Are you sure that it is ami-30be4359?